# C: compiling with -D in make file

Tags: c, makefile

Hi i'm having issues while compiling my c program.
I'm using Makefile to compile it.

this is my make file :

```
# flags per la compilazione
#CFLAGS = -std=c89 -Wpedantic
    
CC = gcc
SO_HEIGHT= SO_HEIGHT=20
SO_WIDTH= SO_WIDTH=60

LIBS=libs/
OBJ = $(LIBS)ipc_utilities.o $(LIBS)utilities.o $(LIBS)dijkstra.o
OBJMAIN = main.o
OBJSOSOURCES=so_sources.o
OBJTAXI=taxi.o
all : utilities main so_sources taxi clean run
main: $(OBJMAIN) $(OBJ)
    $(CC)  $(OBJMAIN) $(OBJ)-o main
so_sources: $(OBJSOSOURCES) $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(OBJSOSOURCES) $(OBJ)  -o so_sources
taxi: $(OBJTAXI) $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(OBJTAXI) $(OBJ)-o taxi
utilities: 
    $(CC)   -c  -D $(SO_HEIGHT) -D $(SO_WIDTH) -o $(LIBS)utilities.o $(LIBS)utilities.c

clean:
    rm -f *.o 
    rm -f $(LIBS)*.o
    clear
    

# il target run si usa talvolta per eseguire l'applicazione
run: 
    ./main
```

---

this is the error i get :

```
gcc   -c  -D SO_HEIGHT=20 -D SO_WIDTH=60 -o libs/utilities.o libs/utilities.c
gcc    -c -o libs/ipc_utilities.o libs/ipc_utilities.c
In file included from libs/ipc_utilities.h:4,
                 from libs/ipc_utilities.c:8:
libs/utilities.h:44:27: error: ‘SO_HEIGHT’ undeclared here (not in a function)
   44 |     struct strada cityMap[SO_HEIGHT][SO_WIDTH];
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~
libs/utilities.h:44:38: error: ‘SO_WIDTH’ undeclared here (not in a function)
   44 |     struct strada cityMap[SO_HEIGHT][SO_WIDTH];
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~
make: *** [<builtin>: libs/ipc_utilities.o] Error 1
```

---

On ipc_utilities.h i include utilities.h :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "utilities.h" // error
```

I'm familiar with makefile ,  anynone can help?

Comment: There should be no space after `-D`, it should be `-D$(SO_HEIGHT)`

Comment: I believe I would advise to re-read a good introduction to makefiles. What is happening is that the default implicit rule for compilation is kicking in at `$(OBJ)` dependency in one of the targets so compiling `gcc    -c -o libs/ipc_utilities.o libs/ipc_utilities.c` with default `$(CC) $(CFLAGS)` rule. Except for that, target names are supported to be generated files and they are _not_ meant to be something readable and dependencies are meant also to be files. So don't `utilities:` but `$(LIBS)utilities.o:  $(LIBS)utilities.c` and such everywhere.

Comment: @koder No, space after `-D` is perfectly acceptable and normal. `gcc -c -D SO_HEIGHT=20 -D SO_WIDTH=60 -xc - <<<'int cityMap[SO_HEIGHT][SO_WIDTH];'` works fine on gcc4.4.

Comment: Same problem with no space

Comment: `$(CC)   -c  -DSO_HEIGHT=$(SO_HEIGHT) -DSO_WIDTH=$(SO_WIDTH) ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to put the pieces together,  but since you need **both** the define name and its value, I would do something like the following:

```
SO_HEIGHT   := 20
SO_WIDTH    := 20

CFLAGS  := -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow
CFLAGS  += -DSO_HEIGHT=$(SO_HEIGHT) -DSO_WIDTH=$(SO_WIDTH)
...
$(CCLD) -o $(APPNAME) $(OBJECTS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

Now you have the define label and value as part of your `CFLAGS` variable (e.g. `-DSO_HEIGHT=$(SO_HEIGHT)`) you do not need to include anything further in your makefile rule.

---

Of Course, you could also simply do:

```
SO_HEIGHT   := SO_HEIGHT=20
SO_WIDTH    := SO_WIDTH=20

CFLAGS  := -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow
CFLAGS  += -D$(SO_HEIGHT) -D$(SO_WIDTH)
```

It's really however you want to do it.